Upon attempting to deploy React-Native project on android emulator, experience React Native Autolinking Failure
This is a project that was recently building and deploying with no issues, however after some recent node module imports (realm and @react-native-community/net-info) the installation process for "npx react-native run-android" is consistently failing, indicating that the "build/generated/autolinking/autolinking.json" file cannot be found. In an attempt to fix this, I first removed the latest imports, deleted and reinstalled all node modules (with the --force flag), but the error persisted. I then manually created an empty autolinking.json file to get around this, but now I get the error:
"RNGP - Autolinking: Could not find project.android.packageName in react-native config output! Could not autolink packages without this field."
From what I can see, the packageName is defined properly, I'm assuming the error is referring to the manifest file.
Below is the main AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.naturecounter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported = "true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
      <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDQVy5Jju3QBfHWCQJ0RCXoj45VJS-SIys"/> -->
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
      <activity
          android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Is there a react-native command for triggering linking? Or am I missing something in my configuration?
react-native v0.71.14
react v18.2.0
android Gradle plugin: 8.4.1
Gradle version: 8.7-bin

Recently added android packageName to the react-native.config.js file, still experiencing the same build issue

This helped me to fix it. Link is here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/46069#issuecomment-2298066865
1
Add autolinkLibrariesWithApp() within the app/build.gradle file.
 react {
      autolinkLibrariesWithApp()
    }

Remove below lines from app/build.gradle file.
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")    applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

4
Remove below line from settings.gradle file.
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

5
Add below lines above the rootProject.name property.
pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'ProjectName'

6
Delete the .build,folder from android
7
Remove node_modules, yarn.lock file and run yarn android command to build the application
Hope it helps you too

thanks for the input! Was able to build and deploy to android emulator successfully by following the above steps

Today I faced this issue and decided to leave a comment—maybe it will help someone.
It turned out I had Node.js version 16 installed, while the project was created with version 20.
I switched my Node.js version to 20, and it worked

Worked for me!!!!

This was it for me, I had switched to node 16, but was built in node 18

Solution to Autolinking Error in React Native:
If you're facing the error:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateAutolinkingPackageList'.

RNGP - Autolinking: Could not find project.android.packageName in react-native config output! Could not autolink packages without this field.

Follow these steps to fix it:
1. Remove the autolinking.json file:
**run **=> rm -rf android/build/generated/autolinking/autolinking.json
2. Clean the Android build:
cd android
./gradlew clean
3.Rebuild the Android project:
cd ..
yarn react-native run-android
4.Clear the Metro cache:
yarn start --reset-cache
if not using yarn
cd .. && npx react-native run-android
npx react-native start --reset-cache
These steps should resolve the autolinking issue and allow the project to build successfully.

I had a similar issue but with expo.
Basically I had a locally built android folder, then I updated from expo SDK 51 to 52 and from react native 0.74 to 0.76 which I believe was causing this issue.
What resolved it for me was to

delete the android folder
then run eas run:android
then run eas build -p android --local


The error occurs during the build process in a React Native project, specifically when the autolinking process fails with the message:
RNGP - Autolinking: Could not find project.android.packageName in react-native config output! Could not autolink packages without this field.

This happens because the React Native CLI cannot find the packageName needed to correctly link the Android project.
Solution:

Step 1: Create or Update react-native.config.js
If you don't already have a react-native.config.js file in the root directory of your project, create one. This file is used to configure the React Native CLI.
 module. Exports = {
 project: {
 android: {
   packageName: 'com.nymvp', // Replace 'com.nymvp' with your actual 
  package name
 },
},
};



This configuration explicitly defines the packageName for your Android project, which the React Native CLI uses during the autolinking process.

Step 2:
Remove the Existing Autolinking JSON File
Next, remove the existing autolinking JSON file to ensure that the autolinking process generates a new file based on the updated configuration:
you can manually delete it from


/ProjectName/android/build/generated/autolinking/autolinking.json

or
by running command:
rm -rf android/build/generated/autolinking/autolinking.json

This file stores the results of the previous autolinking process, which may be outdated or incorrect if the packageName was not set properly.

Step 3:
Clean and Rebuild the Project
After making these changes, it's important to clean and rebuild the project to apply the new configuration:
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-android



Tried this, unfortunately I still get the error that the autolinking.json input file doesn't exist after performing all the steps mentioned. Definitely have the android packageName defined in react-native.config.js, removed any pre-existing autolinking.json file and performed a clean followed by a build. I've upgraded gradle wrapper to 8.8, android gradle plugin to 8.5 and react native to 0.74.5, doesn't appear to make a difference
